# MySQL join + GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two MySQL tables and want to join it correctly by one sql query.

**Table "users"**

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | email_1@test.com |
| 2 | email_2@test.com |
| 3 | email_3@test.com |
| 4 | email_4@test.com |
| 5 | email_5@test.com |

**Table "group_user"**

| user_id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 |

**I want to have result:**

| id | email | group_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email_1@test.com | 1 |
| 2 | email_2@test.com | 1,5,6 |
| 3 | email_3@test.com | 5,6 |
| 4 | email_4@test.com | 1 |
| 5 | email_5@test.com | 5 |

I don't understand how to do it correctly. Please help me write the correct query to MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the aggregate function [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

```
SELECT user_id, email, GROUP_CONCAT(group_id) AS group_ids
FROM users u
INNER JOIN group_user g ON u.id = g.user_id
GROUP BY user_id, email
```

Answer (score 1):

with postgres you can use this request:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, array_agg(gu.group_id)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN group_user gu
ON u.id = gu.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.email;
```

source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE